# why is my footer wider than my bootstrapcontainer

Tags: footer

I put my footer on the last row of an col-md-12 container and expect the footer to be the same width as the col-md-12 container. Instead of this it starts corretly on the left side with the container, but on the right side it ends at the display border and not at the container.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>footertest</title>

  <!-- bootstrap -->
 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">



 <style>
    .myleft{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(227, 236, 97);
    height: 400px;
    }

    .myright{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(19, 197, 49);
    min-height:100%;
    }


    .mytest{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: aqua;
    height:50px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    }

 </style>

</head>

<body>
      <div class="container">
        <div  class="row " >  <!-- arbeitsbereich links + rechts- -->
            <div  class="col-md-6 myleft">  <!-- linke Haelfte -->
                this is the left side (col-md-6)
            </div>

            <div  class="col-md-6 myright" >    <!-- test1 hat den style lightblue im css-->
                <!-- rechte Haelfte--> 
                this is the right side (col-md-6)             
            </div>
        </div>


        <div  class="row " >
          <div  class="col-md-12 mytest">
            this is my footer. It starts correctly at the left side of the container, but ends at the right site of the display instead of the container
          </div>  
        </div>

      </div>   
            

</body>
</html>
```

here is a screenshot of the result:

https://zaunraum.de//IsMobileTest/footer.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It's because width of a fixed position is not relative to the place where it's displayed (it's like if you place this element with position absolute)

the element is displayed out of container and don't take into consideration width of col-md-12

like you put 100% width to class .mytestin, this one will take width of entire page

you have different way to fixed your issue :

- put a max-width on your footer
- put a margin on page

but in all cases you have to considered your element as a standalone one

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by creating the footer as a standalone element (as suggested by jeremy-denis) and then inserting a col-md-12 container into the footer. This then behaves natrlih exactly like the main container.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: great if you succeed to solve your issue ;) may i ask you to mark my reply if it help you to found the solution ?